# What is OEM-dependent consulting?

Tags: definition

Is this a common term in consulting?

Our prof mentiones this, but I can't find any definition in the inet.

Comment: What course is it and in what context is the term being used?

Comment: The course is called _Consulting_. The term was used within the definition of typologies of consulting ventures.

Comment: Based on your comments and answers below, you seem to have a clear definition of the term, an understanding that it is not a project management term and an understanding of where it does fit into consulting.  What is your question?

Comment: This question is not about project management within the scope of our Help Center.

Answer (score 1):

OEM = original equipment manufacture (aka owner of hardware or software - Apple, Dell, HP, IBM, SAP, Oracle are all OEM's)

Typically an OEM must supply consulting for their products.  Now, third-party consulting firms like Accenture could choose to train their folks on a product and deliver product specific consulting like an SAP Practice at Accenture.

My guess is that OEM-Dependent consulting is that consulting that ONLY the OEM vendor delivers because is so specialized or perishable that the 3rd Party teams can not profitably deliver that service.  For example, API consulting on a specific low use module like Admin.

In a young start-up with no critical mass and no 3rd Party SI's to deliver services, all of your consulting would be OEM-Dependent.  You as the buyer are dependent on the OEM for that service.

Does that sound like what your instructor is talking about?

Answer (score 0):

I've never heard of it in project management.

Though, it sounds vaguely like Jack Welch's "Voice of the Customer" approach of being hyper-tuned to a customer's specific needs. In this case, sounds like it would be consulting that is completely in-sync with the needs and directions of the OEM that you are providing services to.

Comment: In fact, this terminology is not at home in project management. Although, I thought, that I am able to find an answer here, because project management is substantially related to consulting ventures.

Answer (score 0):

The definition (referencing to my prof, but expressed in own words):

*Offering standardized ERP software systems or parts of it, to integrate into the business processes. Coming with the information technology is the offer, to support the process of implementation, as well as the implementation of another software module or business process optimizations.*

So the OEM-dependent consulting relys on the customer's need of support, by implementing the information technology systems. I hope, this is a fairly clear definition.

Answer (score 0):

I think this refers to an ERP consulting firm.

Enterprise resource planning (ERP) integrates internal and external management information across an entire organization, embracing finance/accounting, manufacturing, sales and service, etc.

OEM is an international firm of consulting experts with a proven track record in implementing custom designed business solutions. This firm supports the integration in Operations, Engineering and Manufacturing with automated IT services.

You can follow the services they offer in the following hyperlink:

http://www.oemconsultants.ca

Maybe your organization has plans to hire these kind of services.

Comment: Hi MON4K0, this was flagged as spam a looong time ago. Not sure why, but looking back on it, your intention was clearly to be helpful. So I went ahead and cleared the flags and restored the -45 rep points that were deducted for this. You clearly aren't a spammer, since you're an active contributor to this site. ;)